# What is the difference between 'in' and 'at' in Javascript stack traces

Tags: javascript, stack-trace

In the Javascript stack traces I encounter I notice the word 'at' being used to denote the function call. e.g.

'at' is being used to denote the location

[image: at]

'in' is being used to denote the location

[image: in]

However I have also seen stacktraces that use the word 'in' which appear to denote the same thing as 'at', namely to denote a function call.

What is the difference between 'in' and 'at' in Javascript stack traces?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or textual stack traces that demonstrate both uses? Which browsers or other environments output “at” or “in”? Why do you think there is a difference?

Comment: Just added some screenshots